# jQuery: Ignore class in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

What I have is a div and inside that div various elements. Now I wan't to add a click event to the div, but don't add it to elements inside the div with a certain class.

The thing is, the elements can be on different levels which I don't know, so `$("#mydiv > :not(.disabled)").click` does not work.

How do I exclude child elements with a certain class?

Comment: Do you want to add click event to #mydiv itself or the elements inside? It's not clear so far.

Comment: I want to add it to #mydiv and ignore the event when .disabled is clicked which is inside #mydiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#mydiv").on("click",function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest("#mydiv .disabled").length){
    return
  }else{
    //do whatever you want to do.
  }
});
```

simply ignore the event if the clicked element is being `.disabled`

Comment: That's not safe. What if there was a .disabled element further up the DOM hierarchy?

Comment: Since you know the selector for the event listener."#mydiv .disabled" guarantees that would never happen.

Comment: Not necessarily. `.closest("#mydiv .disabled")` will find any .disabled element up the hierarchy within #myDiv, not necessarily the one you are interested in. It may be unlikely, but should be allowed for.

Comment: He wants to ignore click events of .disabled element within #mydiv but listens click events on other elements in #mydiv.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty close to what you want. You just have to switch from the immediate child selector to the general one.

Example Markup:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="enabled"></div>
  <div class="enabled"></div>
  <div class="disabled"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="disabled"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#myDiv > :not(.disabled)")
```

Will ignore the first disabled class but not affect any nested elements because ">" only selects children on the next level down.

```js
$("#myDiv :not(.disabled)")
```

Will select all children of #myDiv excluding .disabled anywhere in the hierarchy.

As @Robo Robok points out, its unclear whether you want the selector on #myDiv or on its child elements. In this example, clicking within #myDiv not on a disabled area will produce the desired effect. However, if there is space inside your div like padding or space between children, clicking there will have no effect.

What I think you want to do is put the selector on the div and then prevent bubbling from the disabled areas.

```js
$("#myDiv").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".disabled")) {
      return;
    }
  
    //your code
});
```

Comment: This one has same problem as the answer by `thisismarksantiago` - it works correctly for all except top level. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jt74mg6w/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Sushi's answer is OK if you want to suppress clicks on disabled elements AND any descendant element.

If under some circumstance you had a .disabled element with non-disabled descendants, and you wanted :

- to allow clicks on the non-disabled descendants to trigger the `#myDiv` click action
- to inhibit clicks on .disabled elements themselves

then do as follows :

```
$("#mydiv").on("click", function(e) {
    // desired action.
}).find(".disabled").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The circumstance most likely to cause this consideration to be an issue is a page with heavy absolute positioning, where DOM hierarchy is not reflected in the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
$("#mydiv :not(.disabled)").on("click", function (event) {
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevents multiple-firing of event
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imelgrat/0dv3u6wj/) with an example. It displays a "click" message when clicking on non-disabled elements. However, if you don't catch click events when disabled elements are inside enabled elements, the event will fire. The solution is to catch the click event on .disabled elements and just stop propagation of the click event.

```
$("#mydiv .disabled").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevents bubbling up of event
});
```